# The word like can be used as a noun

Tags: word-usage

A : This is something that we have been doing for the past 7 months. And this is something that I
have been doing for like more than 5
years.

This is A's talking in front of somebody. I want to translate the second sentence :

I prepared after targeting the completeness which can be obtained from our 5 years or more labors

= This is something that I
have been doing for like (or completeness) that we have been doing more than 5 years

= This is something that I
have been doing for like more than 5
years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is something that I have been doing for like more than 5 years.

I can interpret this two ways.

1. *Like* can be a filler word, similar to *um* or *uh*, that has essentially no meaning but gives the speaker more time to think what they want to say next.
2. If spoken more deliberately, *like* can mean "about" or "approximately". B may be saying that they have been doing something for approximately 5 years. Using "like" in this sense together with "more than" is a bit illogical, but real-world speech often is.

Comment: When I saw the video, 1 is mor suitable. I understand as follows : He prepared for last five years and during recent 7 months  he and her prepared together.

Comment: That's very likely if the speakers are American and under 50 years old.

Answer (score 1):

*Like* *is* used a noun in the context of social media sites like Facebook. (*The post has hundreds of **likes**.*) But it's not being used as a noun in the sentence in the question.

In the sentence in the question, it's modifying an adjective, so it's being used as an adverb in general, and as an interjection specifically.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like):

> **like** *adverb*
>   4 : NEARLY, APPROXIMATELY
>   // the actual interest is more *like* 18 percent
>   —used interjectionally in informal speech with expressions of measurement
>   // it was, *like*, five feet long
>   // goes there every day, *like*

In the example in the question, *like* is being used as an interjectional adverb to modify an expression of the measurement of time.

Also, although the use of commas is stylistic, it would probably be more common to use them in this case:

> And this is something that I have been doing for, *like*, more than 5 years.